# Consulta para mostrar el nombre de la categoría de los productos mas vendidos

Tags: postgresql

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Consulta para mostrar el nombre de la categoría de los productos mas vendidos

Comment: Pregunta repetida [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/200895/mostrar-el-nombre-de-la-categor%C3%ADa-de-los-productos-mas-vendidos)

Answer (score 0):

La siguiente consulta te devuelve el nombre de la categoría (y el nombre del producto y la cantidad) del producto más vendido, si quieres los `n` productos más vendidos hay que cambiar el 1 del `limit`.

```
with ventas_por_producto as (
  select productoid, descripcion, nombrecat, sum(cantidad) as vendidos
    from detalleordenes inner join productos using (productoid)
      inner join categorias using (categoriaid)
  group by productoid, descripcion, nombrecat
)
select nombrecat, descripcion, vendidos
  from ventas_por_producto
  order by vendidos desc
  limit 1;
```

*Para la próxima sería ideal que facilites un script de creación de datos de ejemplo y una tabla (armada a mano) con los datos que esperas encontrar. Además si puedes poner lo que intentaste también ayuda a que te ayudemos mejor.*

*Para ello puedes usar una servicio en línea de postgres como: http://rextester.com/JRJE21952 ahí puedes ver la consulta que acá puse y sus resultados (con unos datos de ejemplo)*